# Using `#` in definition

Tags: ruby, function

I realized it is possible to have `#` in a definition:

```
def Foo#bar
   "blah blah"
end
```

But I am not sure what it means. I expected an instance method `bar` defined on class `Foo`, but that does not seem to be the case. What does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#` begins a comment in ruby. You are simply defining a method called `Foo`.

(Note that `Foo#bar` is commonly used to denote "the instance method `bar` of class `Foo`", but it is not a feature of Ruby syntax!)

Comment: @sawa wow you actually made me think for a while that this was alternative to defining this inside of a class :)

Comment: @Darth That was what I wanted, and I tried to see if it works. Hahaha.

Comment: Nope. You can define a class method with `def Foo.bar`, but in order to do an instance method I think you'd need `Foo.class_eval { def bar; ... end }`.